# Should we rename the tag [tag:piracy]

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The tag [piracy](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/piracy)(10 questions) is used on the site to describe the act of copy rights infringement, and there a tag [pirates](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pirates)(2 questions) to describe outlaws on the high seas. I think that they are too similar, in even though the use of piracy as copy right infringement is common place today the word still used to describe the actions of pirates.

I suggest renaming the tag to [copy-rights](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copy-rights) or [intelectual-property](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intelectual-property) to better differentiate it, and to be more inclusive to also cover question like

[Did Steve Jobs say "We've always been shameless about stealing great ideas."?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10730/did-steve-jobs-say-weve-always-been-shameless-about-stealing-great-ideas)

and

[Was Mozart a music pirate?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6909/was-mozart-a-music-pirate)

Which are not about the act of downloading materials that are under the protection of copy rights from the internet, which is the common meaning of piracy.

And, if we do open such a tag, I think you should merge the tag [patents](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patents)(3 questions) under it as well.

Answer (score 3):

I agree, if only for the reason that “piracy” is a horribly loaded term that was probably intentionally chosen by the IP industry malign their opponents and poison the well.

Comment: Indeed. http://copyrightsandcampaigns.blogspot.com/2009/04/piracy-as-copyright-infringement.html?m=1